# Script to Find And Replace

Tags: scripts

new to this forum. I am trying to pull off a weird script, but I am been stuck for some days now.

I have two text files.

Input.txt
Playlist.txt

Input.txt Contains a number that is generated randomly every 4 hours.

```
083107
```

Playlist.txt Contains M3u links.

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="CHAN 1" tvg-logo="" group-title="FTA",CHAN 1
http://xxxxx.com:25461/live/**010707**/11/11594.ts#

EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="CHAN " tvg-logo="" group-title="FTA",CHAN 2
http://xxxxx.com:25461/live/**010707**/11/11594.ts
```

So I want to find and replace all the ocurrences of 010707 and replace them with the number inside the Input.txt file in this case 083107 then save a copy of the Playlist.txt file, and every 4 hours replace that number again with the one inside the Input.txt file and so on.

I already have put together a very ugly but working script that uses grep and wget to download some files of the internet and generate that Input.txt file.

Thank you for your time.

***EDIT***

Every day I download a M3uPlaylist file "Playlist.m3u" from some site, lets call it example.com.

But, the page "example.com" generates a new user every 4 hours and I need to replace it in the m3u file manually using find (Old user number) and replace (new user number).

```
/live/**010707**/11/11594.ts to /live/**083107**/11/11594.ts
```

This is what I came up with:

## I point wget to example.com  and download only the part of the website containing the user.

```
wget -qO- 19X.71.5X.252 | grep -oP 'User:.*' > User.txt
```

User: 083107             Password: 11

## Then I use grep to generate a "cleaner" file.

```
grep 'User' User.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*' > Numbers.txt
```

083107
11
2

## After that I use the "head" command to make a file containing the user name only.

```
head -1 Numbers.txt > input.txt
```

083107

What i want to acomplish is to automatically update the Playlist.txt (or M3u) file with the new user number example.com is generating every 4 hours. Using the input.txt file for that.

This is the part of example.com source code that contains the user.

```
<!--You need to visit this site every 4 hours in order to get a new user-->
        <div id="domainSearch" class="domain-search--section bg--overlay-color bg--overlay-opacity-95 pd--80-0 text-center" data-bg-img="img/domain-search-img/bg.jpg">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Domain Search Title Start -->
                <div class="domain-search--title">
                     <h2 class="h3">Whatsapp: &nbsp;&nbsp; +52 </h3>
                    <h2 class="h2">User: 083107      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Password: 11</h2>
```

Comment: It's probably easier to create a template file in which the number is represented by some unambiguous placeholder, and the generate a fresh file from the template each time. Otherwise you're going to need to record the current value and construct a new replacement command each time.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the script that creates `Input.txt` as well as what’s done with `Playlist.txt` in the end – there may be a *much* easier way to do the whole thing. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: is "010707" the *previous* value of Input.txt?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes it is, it changes every 4 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this:

```bsh
# extract the userid from the current playlist
prev_user=$(grep -Po '(?<=live/).+(?=/11/11594.ts)' Playlist.txt | head -1)

# find the current userid
current_user=$(wget -qO- 19X.71.5X.252 | grep -oP 'User:\s*\K\S+')

# update the playlist
sed_body=$(printf 's/\<%s\>/%s/g' "$prev_user" "$current_user")
sed -i "$sed_body" Playlist.txt
```

That grep regex should just find the non-space characters after "User:" (i.e. the userid). This way you don't need the other temp files.

I also use the `\<` and `\>` word boundary markers for the sed regex so you match the userid as a whole word.

Answer (score 1):

## Updated version

Considering the fact that "010707" is the previous content of "Input.txt" file, I would change the script a bit.

```bsh
PREVIOUS_INPUT=$1
while true
do
   NEW_INPUT=$(cat Input.txt)
   sed -i.backup "s/$PREVIOUS_INPUT/$NEW_INPUT/g" Playlist.txt
   PREVIOUS_INPUT=$NEW_INPUT
   sleep 14400
done
```

Run it with `<name-of-the-script>.sh 010707`.

And if You would append instead of overwrite: `head -1 Numbers.txt >> Input.txt`, it all would be even easier.

```bsh
while true
do
   sed -i.backup "s/$(tail -2 Input.txt | head -1)/$(tail -1 Input.txt)/g" Playlist.txt
   sleep 14400
done
```

## Original answer

`sed` is what You need: https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-sed/ .

```bsh
while true
do
   sed "s/010707/$(cat Input.txt)/g" Playlist.txt > NewPlaylist.txt
   sleep 14400
done
```

should work.

You could also edit `Playlist.txt` "in place" with
`-i` parameter. I would suggest using `-i.backup` in this case though, to store a previous version of the file as `Playlist.txt.backup`.

You could also watch for `Input.txt` file change and then call `sed`.

Comment: In-place edit won't work more than once because the 010707 then has vanished.

Comment: How about using `date` for the output filename, e.g. `>$(date +%F_%R)_Playlist.txt` for `2018-06-07_12:00_Playlist.txt`, `2018-06-07_16:00_Playlist.txt`and so on – this way you don’t overwrite anything.

Comment: @Perl , it depends what's going to happen to the file in between. Orlando said he's going to copy it. I assumed that "Playlist.txt" may be overwritten after that. I'll update the answer considering the Orlandos' last comment. Thank You.

Comment: @dessert , sure can do. Feel free to update the answer adding Your version of the script if You want. But please - remember about Windows and don't use `:` in the name of  the file! ;)